# How to join in Entity dotnet core / linq?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, join

I've got the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM Movie m INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT movie_id, COUNT(movie_id) as amount
    FROM Watchhistory
    WHERE watch_date >=  DATEADD(day,-3000, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY movie_id
) as a on m.movie_id = a.movie_id
ORDER BY a.amount DESC
```

And the following tables:

[image]

My attempt right now:
`var movies = _context.Movie
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Join(
        _context.Watchhistory.Where(
            w => w.WatchDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).AddDays(-14))
        .GroupBy(w => w.MovieId)
        .Select(m => new { amount = m.Count(), mID = m.Key })
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.amount)
        .Select(a => new { movieid = a.mID }),
        m => m.MovieId, w => w.movieid, (m, w) => m);`

I cant seem to get it working in c# dotnet entity. How do I use a right outer join in linq?

Comment: Let's see what you've tried and work off that

Comment: Why do you even need a right outer join? Assuming that your foreign keys are set up properly you can't have a  `movie_id` in the `WatchHistory` table that does not exist in the `Movie` table. An Inner join would suffice.

Comment: stop thinking in sql, think linq. 'right outer join' is an sql concept. @GarethD is right.

Comment: Thank you! Wow, my bad. Inner join is indeed better (how could i be so stupid). 

`var movies = _context.Movie
.AsNoTracking()
.Join(
    _context.Watchhistory.Where(
            w => w.WatchDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).AddDays(-14))
        .GroupBy(w => w.MovieId)
        .Select(m => new { amount = m.Count(), mID = m.Key })
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.amount)
        .Select(a => new { movieid = a.mID }),
    m => m.MovieId, w => w.movieid, (m, w) => m);` see edit.

Answer (score 0):

You rarely use JOIN in LINQ.  Instead just write queries navigate the model.

so

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Movie m INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT movie_id, COUNT(movie_id) as amount
        FROM Watchhistory
        WHERE watch_date >=  DATEADD(day,-3000, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY movie_id
    ) as a on m.movie_id = a.movie_id
    ORDER BY a.amount DESC
```

becomes something like:

```
    var q = from m in db.Movies
            select new {m.MovieID,m.Name, amount = m.WatchHistory.Where( w => w.WatchDate >= ...).Count() };

   var results = q.Where( m => m.amount > 0).OrderByDesc( m => m.amount).ToList();
```

David